# redirect on a Domino HTTP server?

Tags: http, redirect, ibm-domino

Simple question but:-

We have a server running Domino Http server on port 80. We have another apache server running on 8081.

We want to set a DNS entry (say 'Things') to point to a page on the 8081 server. As I see it we need to do some kind of redirect on the Domino server to say that any traffic from hostname 'Things' gets a redirect to "http://server:8081/content/".

So, in summary,  if I type in "http://Things" on my browser I get redirected to "http://server:8081/content/"

Does anyone know how to do this on the Domino Http server?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Redirects in domino are usually done using web site rules documents. You can define a number of things in here such as:

- Substitution
- Redirection
- Directory
- HTTP response header

So you would setup a redirect for your URL, to redirect to the URL on the Apache server. You can read more details on web site rule documents [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_admin.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/d9a27003749ea70985256c1d00397b7a?OpenDocument&Highlight=0,redirect), and get the technical details of setting one up [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/a5e4b2f240e7763785256c1d00397bac?OpenDocument).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to run multiple web server software within the same OS would be to set up multiple IP addresses and DNS entries accordingly (even on the same network controller) and have each web server bound to its own IP address. Both Domino and Apache can do this.

Then you don't need to mess around with funky ports numbers and HTTP redirects.